# Dynamic UI in iphone

Tags: iphone

I have a plan of creating Dynamic UI in iphone using webservices ..that is the UI will be build according to the xml content from a webservice.
I need to know some of your suggestions regarding this... where will i get resources for building such an app... are there any tutorials available.....?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into the Serialization of Objects in Objective C runtime.
Serialization in Cocoa is called Archiving/Unarchiving

You may find a nice [Apple's guide here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047i)